# Changing <div> to <a> messing up my styles

Tags: html, css

I was stay far from coding for a very long time but today I start to do some code, and have fun with html and styling, lol. My goal was to create a simple card gallery which is very simple and every 6 year old child can do in a few lines of some css and html. As you can see I failed and ended up here in stackoverflow looking for some help.
The problem accured when I tried to change my *div* card into an *a* link, back in the days it worked well as I can remember. Since there was an premade class with styles, you simply changed the tag and everything was well, except you should change colors on that *a* may be. But today when I did it, my card... it just messed up... I got really confused. I also tried some different approaches, for example wrap the *div* into *a* and it looks wierd too. So the main questions are:

1. Why everyting is messed up, when simply change tag to *a* from *div* (we have premade css class!)? But the card is like became divided into 2 parts...
2. When I tried to wrapped *div* card with *a*. In my DOM I can see that this *a* is like duplicate itself inside DOM on every element inside itself.
   Can anyone explain what is going on here and what is a good approach nowadays?
   https://jsfiddle.net/49Lj8dxz/2/

```css
.my-cards-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.my-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  max-width: 228px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: grey;
}
.my-img-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: block; 
}
.my-img-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-cards-container">
  

<div class="my-card">
  <div class="my-img-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="fishy-img">
  </div>
  <div class="my-content-container">
    <h2>Fishy title 1</h2>
    <div>Fishy text 1</div>
    <div class="my-links-container">
      <a href="#">link 1</a>
      <a href="#">link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="my-card">
  <div class="my-img-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="fishy-img">
  </div>
  <div class="my-content-container">
    <h2>Fishy title 2</h2>
    <div>Fishy text 2</div>
    <div class="my-links-container">
      <a href="#">link 1</a>
      <a href="#">link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>


<a href="#">
<div class="my-card">
  <div class="my-img-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="fishy-img">
  </div>
  <div class="my-content-container">
    <h2>Fishy title 3</h2>
    <div>Fishy text 3</div>
    <div class="my-links-container">
      <a href="#">link 1</a>
      <a href="#">link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Given that it's invalid to nest an anchor (`<a>`) element within another anchor element your HTML is invalid and, if you want to have anchors within your cards, you'd be wise not to use an anchor for your card element.

Comment: so the problem is in that nested a inside a? its just invalid? I thought i could play with they z-indexs later))

Comment: It seems like it's a thing. nesting this tags inside each other is breking things. And to achieve my idea i have to use an link container element outside the link with position absolute. so it's look like nested :O

Comment: I agree, you can't have those `<a>` tags inside another `<a>` tag. Of the 3 cards in your jsfiddle, `Fishy-title-1` is the most correct.